# Implement GitHub repos using Tanstack Query into Next.js 13 project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js13, tanstackreact-query

I'm trying to implement my latest repositories from GitHub (GitHub API) into my project and stuck here for days. I keep getting an error "No overload matches this call." in ['repos', data.githubUserName]. Do I add more types or is my syntax here for the API wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Enviroment

- Next.js 13
- Tanstack Query
- TypeScript

```
import { useQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import axios from 'axios';

export function useGetRepos() {
  const fetchRepos = async (username: string, token: string) => {
    const res = await axios.get(
      `https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=user:${username}+sort:author-date-asc`
    );
    // fetch 6 latest repos
    return res.data.items.slice(0, 6);
  };
  return useQuery(['repos', data.githubUserName], fetchRepos);
}
```

layout.tsx

```
import type { Metadata } from 'next';
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google';
import QueryProvider from '@/providers/QueryProvider';

import NavBar from './components/NavBar';
import Footer from './components/Footer';

import './globals.css';

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: '',
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang='en'>
      <body suppressHydrationWarning={true} className={inter.className}>
        <QueryProvider>
          <main>
            {children}
          </main>
        </QueryProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

provider/QueryProvider.tsx

```
'use client';

import { useState } from 'react';
import { QueryClientProvider, QueryClient } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from '@tanstack/react-query-devtools';

const QueryProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const [queryClient] = useState(() => new QueryClient());

  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      {children}
      <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
};

export default QueryProvider;
```

I am expecting to render my 6 latest repositories from GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there are syntax issues in the query.

**No overload matches this call**  refers to a typescript error. It expected the second argument to be of type `QueryFunction<any, string[]>`, whereas the in the code snippet you've shared it is provided with `(username: string, token: string)`.

Below is the corrected version.

```
import { useQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import axios from 'axios';

export function useGetRepos() {
  const fetchRepos = async (username: string, token: string) => {
    const res = await axios.get(
      `https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=user:${username}+sort:author-date-asc`
    );
    // fetch 6 latest repos
    return res.data.items.slice(0, 6);
  };
  return useQuery(['repos', data.githubUserName], () => fetchRepos);
}
```

Comment: I appreciate for your response. I'm still getting the same error in line "['repos', data.githubUserName]".

Comment: @eobcre Could you share a code sandbox link or the new error you are getting?